# Angular2 Routing from Navbar (AppComponent)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having an issue with Routing in Angular2 where routing creates a new object and keeps the old object.

My navbar and [Home] button resides in the AppComponent.

```
.. app.html
<a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['Auth']">Home</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
..
```

The router defaults to AuthComponent at the start.

```
.. app.component.ts
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', as: 'Auth', component: AuthComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])
..
```

I'll demonstrate the scenario by logging a message in AuthComponent's constructor.

```
.. auth.component.ts
constructor(private _router: Router) {
    console.log("Constructing AuthComponent");
    this.router = _router;
}
..
```

The response to clicking the Home button will produce `Constructing AuthComponent` everytime it is clicked thus creating a new object. (I can confirm that the old objects do still exist)

I want to be able to route to somewhere and then route back into AuthComponent while still having access to my data I set previously.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEh4hvz8r1A440iUvs1Y?p=preview).

<strike>I'm currently using `2.0.0-beta.7`</strike> Updated to `2.0.0.beta.9`

Comment: As soon as I find the full solution I'll add it and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `CanReuse` interface on your component and its `routerCanReuse` method. This way, if this method returns `true`, the same instance of the component will be used within routing:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
class SomeComponent implements CanReuse {
  constructor(params: RouteParams) {

  }

  routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html

Comment: Hi I just added this to my Auth and now a new Component. 
`App -> Auth -> NewComponent`
When pressing Home from Auth it gets reused, but not from NewComponent. The routing I want is as following `App-> Auth -> NewComponent -> Auth(Reuse) -> NewComponent(Reuse)`

Comment: You mean within the `AuthComponent` class? What is `NewComponent`? Another component?

Comment: Yes another component. I also updated to Angular 2.0.9-beta just in case.

Comment: So you mean, the same instance of `AuthComponent` is used but a new instance is created for the `NewComponent` which is used within the template of `AuthComponent`. Right?

Comment: I don't know how to say it. Let me try and create a plunker quickly.

Comment: Hi, Ok. I've recreated the problem.  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEh4hvz8r1A440iUvs1Y?p=preview) (See the console log for what is happening). The button [Route to X] will be a callback from a Javascript service in my program that calls the function the button calls.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction with the CanReuse. I've found other SO topics regarding the object creation issue. I'll investigate further.